# Crystal Report prints only the 1st page, 2nd page is blank

Tags: asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I have a Web Forms project that uses Crystal Report 13.0.22 to print out reports.

I have a problem with one particular report, that it is only able to print out the 1st page of report, while the 2nd page is being cut off resulting in only blank 2nd page. All of this while the data is still available to be printed out.

The other reports works fine but this one report. So far I tried removing the page footer section, but to no solution.

I am still learning about this. Can anyone give me any clue/pointer to as why is this happening ?
Thanks

Comment: left click the report and go to design->default settings->set the **grid size** as 0.001 and your **box size should be in report footer**

Comment: It says the grid size should be between 0.1 to 0.01 inch. The option 'snap to grid' is checked, 'show grid' is not

Comment: I tried 0.01 inch and multiple options of the grid, still no solution.

Comment: The solution is to set the CrystalReportViewer object property crObj.SeparatePages = false; This fixes it for me.